# Oracle: Passing Associative Array To Nested Table For Use in SQL Statement from C#

Tags: c#, arrays, oracle

I'm attempting to pass an array of numbers to an oracle stored procedure so I can process in bulk.  I have to pass the associative array in and then populate a nested table with the contents.  Is there a better way to pass an array of numbers or varchar2 to a stored procedure in oracle?  Am I doing this right? :)

I've looked at temp tables and pipeline functions too as alternatives to this working method below.

```
create or replace type t_number_table as table of number;

create or replace package numberarray_pkg
as
    type t_numbers is table of number index by pls_integer;
    type t_cursor is ref cursor;

    procedure passarray(
      paymentids in t_numbers,
      io_cursor in out t_cursor);

end numberarray_pkg;
/

create or replace package body numberarray_pkg
as
    procedure passarray(paymentids in t_numbers, io_cursor in out t_cursor) as
      v_number_table t_number_table;
      v_cursor       t_cursor;
    begin
      v_number_table := t_number_table();
      v_number_table.extend(paymentids.count);

      for i in 1 .. paymentids.count loop
        v_number_table(i) := paymentids(i);
      end loop;

      open v_cursor for
        select column_value from table(v_number_table);

      io_cursor := v_cursor;
    end passarray;
end numberarray_pkg;
/
```

Comment: I'm populating the array in C# and reading the collection from a flat file.  The only way I could pass the array of values to the stored procedure was by using the oracle associative array.

    
`new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "payment_ids",
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32,
        CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
        Value = array,
        Size = array.Length
    }`

Thanks for looking at my question, Alex.

Comment: I see, I hadn't realised you couldn't use SQL table types like you can from Java. You should probably add that info to the question though, and tag it as C#.

Comment: like the nested table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script of body creation you must declare a default variable like this:

```
 type t_numbers is table of number index by pls_integer;
 nullNumber t_numbers;
```

In the specification of the procedure:

```
 procedure passarray(
      paymentids in t_numbers default nullNumber,
      io_cursor in out t_cursor);
```

And in code you must pass the collection as an array (important) only if the array has at least one value.